# Intuition of Taylor Series - Specifying the function basis of one point only

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion, intuition

The Taylor expansion of an infinitely differentiable function is
$f(x)=f(a)+\frac{f'(a)}{1!} (x-a)+ \frac{f''(a)}{2!} (x-a)^2+\frac{f'''(a)}{3!}(x-a)^3+...$

I understand, the derivation of this formula. However, the fact I can not fathom is how we can find the value of the function at any point given all the nth order derivative at one single point. This means if I know the slope, slope of slope and so on, at one single point, I will know the value of any other point, how far may it be. (I am considering infinite radius of convergence)

Is there any intuitive explanation, how can I determine the value of the function at one point basis of another point, probably very far.

Comment: A key terminology to look up would be *analytic* function.

Comment: It turns out that the hypothesis of infinite radius of convergence is *very* strong, you put it in a parenthetical but it is exactly the reason that this works. Generically I believe a Taylor series will have zero radius of convergence.